# What copyright do I need to worry about in regards to personal photos of sculptures or famous buildings?

Tags: copyright, legal, photography

I would like to use my own photos of sculptures or famous buildings that other people made in **personal projects** (not for real clients) that are poster advertisements and upload them to my Behance account.

Can I use them, quoting the sculpture's artist, without permission? or should I contact the artist?

Comment: You may find this infographic helpful http://thevisualcommunicationguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Infographic_CanIUseThatPicture4.jpg

Comment: Where does the sculpture come into it?

Comment: I think this may be a better question for law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the laws in your specific country since there are differences all around the world.

To be honest with you, legal considerations aside, it would make sense to ask the sculptor's/owner's permission. It would certainly do no harm. You might find they might even be enthusiastic about such a project.

Assume nothing. When in doubt, err on the side of caution, or employ a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a picture of a famous building, I suggest looking at the place's website. They are likely to have rules about how pictures of the place can be used. Just because it's famous doesn't mean it is considered "public property." Taking a picture of someone's famous home may require the owner giving a property release.